# proving $\phi$ does not isolate any complete type implies $CB(\phi)\geq 1$

Tags: model-theory

I'm trying to understand the definition of a cantor-bendixson rank for a formula. It is defined as (in my notation) for $\phi(x)$ in fixed $L$ and complete theory $T$,

(i)$CB(\phi(x))\geq 0$ if $\phi$ is consistent with $T$

(ii)$CB(\phi(x))\geq\alpha$($\alpha$ is limit ordinal) if $CB(\phi(x))\geq\beta$ for all $\beta<\alpha$

(iii)$CB(\phi(x))\geq\alpha +1$ if there's a pairwise inconsistent $(\phi_i |i<\omega)$ such that $CB(\phi(x) \wedge \phi_i (x)\geq\alpha$

I think CB-rank measures a kind of degree of nonisolatedness of $[\phi]=\{p\in S_n (T) | \phi\in p\}$ where $S_n(T)$ is a stone space consisting complete types of $T$. I'm tryng to prove if $\phi$ does not isolate any $p\in S_n(T)$, then $CB(\phi)\geq 1$.

I thought since $\phi$ does not isolate any complete types, $|[\phi]|\geq\omega$ since stone space is hausdorff. then I thought I have to pick pairwise inconsistent formulas from different types in $[\phi]$. but I couldn't proceed anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to prove is not true. Fix a language $L$ with two constant symbols $c$ and $d$ and any complete theory $T$ which proves $c\neq d$. Let $\varphi(x)$ be the formula $(x = c)\lor (x = d)$. Then $\varphi(x)$ has CB-rank $0$, but it does not isolate any type: there are two types consistent with $\varphi(x)$, namely those isolated by $x = c$ and $x = d$.

This also provides a counterexample to your assertion that if $\varphi$ does not isolate a complete type, then $|[\varphi]|\geq \omega$, since we have $|[\varphi]| = 2$.

The correct statement is that the following are equivalent:

1. $\text{CB}(\varphi(x))\geq 1$.
2. *Some* non-isolated type contains $\varphi(x)$.
3. $|[\varphi]|$ is infinite.

Comment: Thanks for correction. Can I have hint for proving 2 or 3 implies 1? I can prove 1=>2 and 2<=>3 but not 2 or 3 implies 1..

Comment: @fbg Let $p$ be a non-isolated type. Pick some consistent formula $\varphi_1$ in $p$. Since it doesn't isolate $p$, there is some $\varphi_2$ in $p$ such that $\lnot\varphi_2$ is also consistent with $\varphi_1$. Continue by induction.

Comment: Then $\lnot\varphi_1$, $\varphi_1\land\lnot\varphi_2$, $\varphi_1\land\varphi_2\land\lnot\varphi_3$, etc. are each consistent, but pairwise inconsistent.

Comment: Oh.. This is what I was looking for. Thanks!!